# Use of static_assert forbidden in Android project

Tags: android-ndk

I am porting some C++ code to Android. One of the source files includes a `webrtc` header file that causes error during compilation. I have reduced the problem to this simple code:

```
template <class T, int n>
struct DefaultDeleter<T[n]> {
  // Never allow someone to declare something like scoped_ptr<int[10]>.
 static_assert(sizeof(T) == -1, "do not use array with size as type");
};
```

The error I get is:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: dummyclient <= dummy.cpp
dummy.cpp:7:3: warning: identifier 'static_assert' will become a keyword in C++0x [-Wc++0x-compat]
dummy.cpp:5:8: error: 'DefaultDeleter' is not a template
dummy.cpp:7:17: error: expected identifier before 'sizeof'
dummy.cpp:7:17: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'sizeof'
dummy.cpp:7:70: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'static_assert' with no type [-fpermissive]
```

The same code compiles fine on Windows and Linux. Is there some compiler settings that are required for Android? Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the CPPFLAG `-std=c++11`.